# Event handlers not unbound if immediately rebound

Tags: angularjs, jqlite

I have a simple directive which renders a button.

The directive's link function does the following:

1. Bind the 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events.
2. Unbind the 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events.
3. Bind the 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events again.

The handlers for the events log a simple message to the console. I would expect the handler to be invoked once on mouseenter or mouseleave. However they are executed twice as if step 2 never occured.

The code for the directive:

```
function ButtonDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button><span ng-transclude></span></button>',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {          
      function mouseEnterHandler()  {
        console.log('mouse enter');
      }

      function mouseLeaveHandler() {
        console.log('mouse leave');
      }

      element.bind('mouseenter', mouseEnterHandler);
      element.bind('mouseleave', mouseLeaveHandler);

      element.unbind('mouseenter');
      element.unbind('mouseleave');

      element.bind('mouseenter', mouseEnterHandler);
      element.bind('mouseleave', mouseLeaveHandler);
    }
  }
}
```

The following plunker illustrates the issue:

http://plnkr.co/ocXYYZ2jv09Ch7GDRaat

Does anybody have an idea why it behaves this way?

**update**: if you include jQuery instead of falling back on JQLite it works. Alas that it not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the issue appears to be located in JQLite. If you include jQuery it works as expected.

In JQLite the bind() and unbind() functions are just aliases for JQLite.off() and on().

Let's consider the code for the on() function.

```
on: function jqLiteOn(element, type, fn, unsupported) {
    // ...
}
```

This function registers the handlers for the various types of events. Apparently they make an exception for the 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events.

```
if (type === 'mouseenter' || type === 'mouseleave') {
    // Refer to jQuery's implementation of mouseenter & mouseleave
    // Read about mouseenter and mouseleave:
    // http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#link8

    jqLiteOn(element, MOUSE_EVENT_MAP[type], function(event) {
        var target = this, related = event.relatedTarget;
        // For mousenter/leave call the handler if related is outside the target.
        // NB: No relatedTarget if the mouse left/entered the browser window
        if (!related || (related !== target && !target.contains(related))) {
          handle(event, type);
        }
    });
}
```

These events are mapped (MOUSE_EVENT_MAP[type]) to 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' respectively.

```
var MOUSE_EVENT_MAP= { mouseleave: "mouseout", mouseenter: "mouseover"};
```

And then the jqLiteOn(...) function recursively calls itself and registers an anonymous function handler for these mapped events. Afterwards it registers your 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events.

So basically that's why the events handlers are being called multiple times.

A workaround is to also unbind the mouseover and mouseout events.

```
element.unbind('mouseover mouseenter');
element.unbind('mouseout mouseleave');
```

Answer (score 0):

When unbinding, you have to specify the function you want to unbind:

```
  element.bind('mouseenter', mouseEnterHandler);
  element.bind('mouseleave', mouseLeaveHandler);

  element.unbind('mouseenter', mouseEnterHandler);
  element.unbind('mouseleave', mouseLeaveHandler);

  element.bind('mouseenter', mouseEnterHandler);
  element.bind('mouseleave', mouseLeaveHandler);
```

Comment: Yes, true, but that is optional. Also tried it using the function. Same result.

Comment: Yeah you're right, interestingly you can keep duplicating the unbind/bind and the number will increase as well.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is because, as per `mouse enter` each time the mouse enters the target element or it's child element the `mouseenter` event will be fired.

It should be `mouseover` and `mouseout` event instead of `mouseleave` and `mouse enter`

```
  element.bind('mouseover', mouseEnterHandler);
  element.bind('mouseout', mouseLeaveHandler);

  element.unbind('mouseover');
  element.unbind('mouseout');

  element.bind('mouseover', mouseEnterHandler);
  element.bind('mouseout', mouseLeaveHandler);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the problem here. I updated the plunker and removed transclusion from the directive. It's only the button now, removed the span. Same result.

Comment: Did you try with mouseover and mouseout events?

Comment: That is not the issue here. It should unbind the events. I understand that it will bubble up the events for any childs, but there are none in this case. As Mathew Berg mentions in his comment you can  duplicate the bind/unbind sequence as much as you want and the number will increase. Just odd.